# how to display two queries in one mysql table

Tags: mysql

Table 1: rm

```
create table rm(rcod int(5) primary key, qty int(5));
```

Table 2: cs

```
create table cs(cscod int(5)primary key, qty int(5));
```

Table 3: final

```
create table final(icod int(5) primary key, qty int(5));
```

Table 4: cmbine

```
create table cmbine(icod int(5),rcod int(5),rmu int(5),cscod int(5),csu int(5));
```

Now Inserting values:

```
insert into rm values(1,10);
insert into rm values(2,20);

insert into cs values(1,20);
insert into cs values(2,10);

    insert into final values(1,50);

insert into cmbine values(1,1,1,2,5);
insert into cmbine values(1,1,20,1,2);
```

Now I want the results which are coming from the following two queries, I want to merge the columns and make it one. 
Query 1:

```
select rcod, 
    qty 
from rm 
where rcod in (select rcod 
               from cmbine 
               where icod = 1);
```

Query 2:

```
select cscod,
    qty 
from cs 
where cscod in (select cscod 
                from cmbine 
                where icod = 1);
```

I thought this could help but I'm getting error.

```
 select cmbine.icod,
        cmbine.rcod,
        rm.qty,
        (rm.qty*cmbine.rmu),
        cmbine.cscod,
        cs.qty,
        cmbine.csq,
        (cs.qty * cmbine.csq) 
    from rm,
        cs,
        cmbine 
    where rcod in (select rcod 
                   from cmbine 
                   where icod=1) 
        and cscod in (select cscod 
                      from cmbine 
                      where icod=1)
;
```

I hope now the information is sufficient.

Thanks!

How can I do it?

Comment: I can't follow you or what you want. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

@RidamJain To get the results from both queries in one result set use a `UNION`, like this:

```
select icod, 
    qty 
from cs 
where icod in (select distinct cscod 
               from cmbine 
               where icod=100)

UNION

select icod, 
    qty 
from rm 
where rcod in (select distinct rscod 
               from cmbine 
               where icod=100)
```

I don't think you need to have sub queries either. Here is how you would do this without the sub queries:

```
select cs.icod, 
    cs.qty 
from cs
JOIN cmbine AS cm ON cm.cscod = cs.icod
    AND cm.icod = 100
GROUP BY cs.icod

UNION

select rm.icod, 
    rm.qty 
from rm
JOIN cmbine AS cm ON cm.rscod = rm.rcod
    AND cm.icod = 100
GROUP BY rm.icod
```

if you need to tell which result set comes from which query, here is how you would do that:

```
select 'First Query' AS result_source,
    cs.icod, 
    cs.qty 
from cs
JOIN cmbine AS cm ON cm.cscod = cs.icod
    AND cm.icod = 100
GROUP BY cs.icod

UNION

select 'Second Query' AS result_source,
    rm.icod, 
    rm.qty 
from rm
JOIN cmbine AS cm ON cm.rscod = rm.rcod
    AND cm.icod = 100
GROUP BY rm.icod
```

EDIT: as clarification was added to the original question, here is a cleaned up version of the query that should give you the results you asked for. One thing to note: in the definition for `cmbine` you listed the last column as `csu` but in the query it is referenced as `csq`. I took the SQL scripts and mocked up the query in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/678a7a/1).

Here is the final cleaned up version of the query:

```
SELECT `cmbine`.`icod`,
    `cmbine`.`rcod`,
    `rm`.`qty`,
    (`rm`.`qty` * `cmbine`.`rmu`),
    `cmbine`.`cscod`,
    `cs`.`qty`,
    `cmbine`.`csq`,
    (`cs`.`qty` * `cmbine`.`csq`) 
FROM `cmbine`
JOIN `cs` ON `cs`.`cscod` = `cmbine`.`cscod`
JOIN `rm` ON `rm`.`rcod` = `cmbine`.`rcod`
WHERE `cmbine`.`icod` = 1;
```

If this still doesn't get you what you want, just give me some clarification as to what you want and I'll do my best to help.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you know which result belongs to which query, or do you think it doesn't matter?

Comment: the OP has 2 queries and wants to display them "in one table format". i interpret that to mean he wants to display the output of both queries at once, which can be done via a `UNION`, the OP didn't say anything about caring to identify which result set came from which query, just that they be displayed together. if he did want to distinguish the two result sets, he could define a custom column like this `'First Query' AS result_source` in the first query and `'Second Query' AS result_source` in the second query, then he would be able to tell which result set came from which query

Comment: thanks a lot, it helped but still i required some other results.

Comment: @RidamJain I see you added the query you are trying to use to your original post, but there is no clarification as to what your problem is now. Does this query not give you your desired result set? If not, what is happening? Is the data the query is returning wrong? Are you getting an error? What exactly do you mean by "display the results in one table format"? They way your question is worded now is not clear at all. Please clearly list what your issue is now and also give us an example of your desired result set so we can better assist you.

Comment: @RidamJain also it would be very helpful if you would provide the SQL scripts to create the tables you are working with and insert data into them (`CREATE TABLE ....` and  `INSERT INTO .....`)

Comment: I have listed out the desired result should be in that defined fashion, the earlier query you posted gives an output with one columns and its corresponding field but doesn't give the result for the query fields after the union command. so i have written a short format for the result i need. You were not wrong, it's just it wasn't giving the required output.

Comment: @RidamJain you have posted an example of what you want the query to look like, not what your expected result set is. Please give us an example of the columns you want returned in the result set and what the data should look like in those columns. if you would post the SQL scripts to create your tables and populate them with data along with what the result of your query should be it would be a lot easier for us to assist you.

Comment: @RidamJain the revised query you posted does not show the relationships between the tables in your query. I agree with the comment from nbk on your original post, you need to review the instructions on how to produce a minimum reproduceable example of an SQL query
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @RidamJain ok, so what values from your query do you want inserted into the `final` table? obviously `icod` from your query, but the only other column in `final` is `qty`. what value from your query do you want inserted into `final.qty`? there's `rm.qty`, `cs.qty` and 2 other calculated fields in your query. what value do you want to be inserted into `final.qty`?

Comment: finaly.qty is not important.

Comment: the qty in both queries comes from rm and cs tables respectively.